# Improve aging water stained garage door

Tags: wood, painting, garage-door

I would like to improve my water damaged garage door - it seems solid enough but it's an eye sore from inside the garage. The wood structure is water stained heavily as seen below;the outside is painted white and looks fine.

What should I or could I do to improve this? Primer and paint? Do I need to sand first? Seal?

Thanks!

[image: Garage door staining sample]

Comment: Off hand I would think water/liquid is entering where the wood is white and spreading outwards/upwards.  Maybe though the bolt heads?

Comment: Seams a good guess @crip659

Comment: I think your only real option is to keep it painted. Maybe raise the door up enough so you can get paint on the edges of each section. If it's flaking off, scrape it first before repainting (careful of lead).

Comment: Thanks @Z4-tier . What about the interior side? Can I just prime and paint it or what do you suggest here?

Comment: you can paint the interior or leave it unfinished, it won't make a whole lot of difference since it's not exposed to the elements. If you do paint it, make sure you use an exterior paint all around.